# Part of hard drive not encrypted - normal?

Tags: boot, partition

Bought a computer online and had issues installing a fresh OS. When running `lsblk -a`, I receive the following output:

```
    NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
    loop1                     7:1    0 193.5M  1 loop  /snap/vlc/65
    loop6                     7:6    0         0 loop  
    loop4                     7:4    0         0 loop  
    loop2                     7:2    0  83.8M  1 loop  /snap/core/3748
    loop0                     7:0    0 192.8M  1 loop  /snap/vlc/113
    sda                       8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk  
    ├─sda2                    8:2    0     1K  0 part  
    ├─sda5                    8:5    0   238G  0 part  
    │ └─sda5_crypt          253:0    0   238G  0 crypt 
    │   ├─ubuntu--vg-root   253:1    0 230.7G  0 lvm   /
    │   └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:2    0   7.3G  0 lvm   
    │     └─cryptswap1      253:3    0   7.3G  0 crypt [SWAP]
    └─sda1                    8:1    0   487M  0 part  /boot
    loop7                     7:7    0         0 loop  
    loop5                     7:5    0         0 loop  
    loop3                     7:3    0         0 loop
```

My main concer is the sda1 partition which is unencrypted and appears to be operating underneath the OS. Any help/suggestions for reference?

Comment: /boot contains files that are needed to bootstrap the system to an point in which you can decrypt the other partitions.

Answer (score 1):

disambiguation of bootstrapping: any process where a simple system activates a more complicated system.

the bios/EFI {the simple system} of today at least for what i am aware of cannot read or boot an encrypted boot partition therefore your boot "partition" sda  is not encrypted.

Calling it whole "disk"encryption is a misnomer, it's really whole "partition" encryption until you go so far as to encrypt every partition, but you typically cannot encrypt the boot partition because then the BIOS/EFI cannot read it.  And I don't think the partition table is ever encrypted.

the boot partition should not contain any of your data, and should only contain the files, boot loader, and linux kernel which do not need to be encrypted, and there's other ways of mitigating, protecting, or recognizing if those boot files were maliciously modified,  **so one could argue there's little to no reason to need the boot partition encrypted to begin with**.

To answer your question, there's nothing really wrong with what you are observing with your laptop that is how it's currently done.  The implementation of encryption can be done a few different ways, each way with different pros/cons and it can often reduce the ease or flexibility of installing a new or fresh operating system on an existing disk like you mentioned.  The simple solution to that is simply *reformatting* or re-partitioning the entire disk to a clean slate but be aware that deletes everything on the disk, that is ok from some and not ok for others it depends on what your goal is.

you stated: *sda1 partition appears to be operating underneath the OS*

I don't think that is technically true and I would not describe it that way, using the word *underneath* as if something bad or risky is happening.

**some suggestions:**

1. read & web search about booting & disk encryption
2. read & web search about disk paritioning MBT and GPT
3. get yourself some free linux distributions like opensuse, fedora, centos, or others.  If your register with Redhat, or Suse, I believe you can download the enterprise versions Redhat enterprise linux (RHEL) and Suse Linux Enterprise Server (SLES) for trial or development and you can play around and observe first hand how and what encryption schemes are available.